# Seleccionar que parte del JSON quiero mostrar

Tags: javascript, nodejs, twitter

El siguiente código, me devuelve un JSON enorme, pero yo solamente quiero seleccionar 4 parámetros de todos los que me devuelven, lo que estoy haciendo hasta ahora es en `console.log(tweets);` llamo al parámetro que quiero seleccionar, por ejemplo `name`, con `tweets.name`, pero siempre me dice que `name` no está definido. Este sería el código que estoy utilizando.

Los parámetros que quiero sacar de este JSON, se encuentran anidados en una primera instancia en `user`, y dentro de `user` tengo los parámetros `id`, `name`, `location`... que son los cuales pretendo almacenar.

```
twitterperfilesCtrl.getPerfiles = async(req, res) =>{
    const twitterPerfiles = await twitterPerfil.find();
    const contadorPerfiles = await twitterPerfil.countDocuments();
    res.json(twitterPerfiles);
    //console.log(twitterPerfiles[1].screen_name);

    for(i = 0; i < contadorPerfiles; i++){
        if (twitterPerfiles[i].id != true) {
            var params = {screen_name: twitterPerfiles[i].screen_name};
        client.get('statuses/user_timeline', params, function(error, tweets, response) {
            if(!error){
                console.log(tweets);
            }
        });    
        }
      }
    }
```

La documentación de Twitter: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline.html

Comment: Saludos bro, edita tu pregunta y agrega todo el código que utilizas, seguido de la documentación de Twitter y de lo que has intentado, de este modo podemos reproducir tu escenario y ver en dónde está la falla :D

Comment: El parámetro "name" no está en la página de documentación en el nivel que lo quieres sacar. Está en un nivel más profundo.

Comment: @JordiHuertas pero a mi me lo devuelve en el JSON

Comment: ¿Puedes poner lo que te devuelve el `console.log(tweets)`?

Comment: @MauricioContreras Lo he dejado en Pastebin, por que es muy largo, esto es lo que me devuelve en consola, https://pastebin.com/a9civQgd

Comment: Lo que le devuelve console.log(tweets) es exactamente lo que pone en la documentación, y "name" está en niveles inferiores, específicamente dentro de user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como te comenta @JordiHuertas, el problema está en la forma en que deseas acceder a los datos. La documentación de la API de Twitter claramente te indica el tipo de *Response* que obtendrás al realizar una solicitud *GET* a la *URL* con los parámetros adecuados.

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea acceder a las propiedades de un objeto JSON devuelto por la API de Twitter.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Según la [documentación](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline.html) de la API de Twitter, el *Response* que se obtiene al realizar una solicitud *GET*, es un `Array` que contiene los *tweets* que estás solicitando.

Cada elemento del `Array` es un objeto en formato JSON, el cual tiene la siguiente estructura: (Tomado de la documentación de Twitter, he modificado algunos atributos para legibilidad)

```
{
  "created_at": "Thu Apr 06 15:28:43 +0000 2017",
  "id": 850007368138018817,
  "id_str": "850007368138018817",
  "text": "RT @TwitterDev: 1/ Today we’re sharing our vision for the future of the Twitter API platform!nhttps://t.co/XweGngmxlP",
  "truncated": false,
  "entities": { ... }
  "source": "<a href=\"http://twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter Web Client</a>",
  "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
  "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
  "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
  "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
  "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
  "user": { ... },
  "geo": null,
  "coordinates": null,
  "place": null,
  "contributors": null,
  "retweeted_status": { ... },
  "is_quote_status": false,
  "retweet_count": 284,
  "favorite_count": 0,
  "favorited": false,
  "retweeted": false,
  "possibly_sensitive": false,
  "lang": "en"
}
```

Por lo que planteas en tu pregunta, te interesa extraer o guardar los valores correspondientes a `id`, `name`, `location`, etc. que se encuentran dentro del objeto `user` de cada *tweet*.

El objeto `user` de cada *tweet* tiene la siguiente estructura: (tomado de la API de Twitter)

```
"user": {
  "id": 6253282,
  "id_str": "6253282",
  "name": "Twitter API",
  "screen_name": "twitterapi",
  "location": "San Francisco, CA",
  "description": "The Real Twitter API. I tweet about API changes, service issues and happily answer questions about Twitter and our API. Don't get an answer? It's on my website.",
  "url": "http://t.co/78pYTvWfJd",
  "entities": { ... },
  "protected": false,
  "followers_count": 6172353,
  "friends_count": 46,
  "listed_count": 13091,
  "created_at": "Wed May 23 06:01:13 +0000 2007",
  "favourites_count": 26,
  "utc_offset": -25200,
  "time_zone": "Pacific Time (US & Canada)",
  "geo_enabled": true,
  "verified": true,
  "statuses_count": 3583,
  "lang": "en",
  "contributors_enabled": false,
  "is_translator": false,
  "is_translation_enabled": false,
  "profile_background_color": "C0DEED",
  "profile_background_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/656927849/miyt9dpjz77sc0w3d4vj.png",
  "profile_background_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/656927849/miyt9dpjz77sc0w3d4vj.png",
  "profile_background_tile": true,
  "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2284174872/7df3h38zabcvjylnyfe3_normal.png",
  "profile_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2284174872/7df3h38zabcvjylnyfe3_normal.png",
  "profile_banner_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/6253282/1431474710",
  "profile_link_color": "0084B4",
  "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED",
  "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6",
  "profile_text_color": "333333",
  "profile_use_background_image": true,
  "has_extended_profile": false,
  "default_profile": false,
  "default_profile_image": false,
  "following": true,
  "follow_request_sent": false,
  "notifications": false,
  "translator_type": "regular"
}
```

Por lo tanto, para poder acceder a los campos que requieres puedes usar un bucle `for` para recorrer el `Array` de *tweets* o el método `forEach()`.

Tomando la información de lo que subiste a [*pastebin*](https://pastebin.com/a9civQgd), esta sería una forma de obtener la data:

```js
//Supongamos que 'tweets' es la respuesta de la API y contiene lo siguiente:

const tweets = [
  { created_at: 'Mon Apr 08 08:01:00 +0000 2019',
    id: 1115162612998787100,
    id_str: '1115162612998787072',
    text:
     'Editorial | El sistema de pensiones no está en quiebra; hay que confiar en la negociación social y política para ga… https://t.co/larIH30qja',
    truncated: true,
    entities:
     { hashtags: [], symbols: [], user_mentions: [], urls: [Array] },
    source:
     '<a href="https://about.twitter.com/products/tweetdeck" rel="nofollow">TweetDeck</a>',
    in_reply_to_status_id: null,
    in_reply_to_status_id_str: null,
    in_reply_to_user_id: null,
    in_reply_to_user_id_str: null,
    in_reply_to_screen_name: null,
    user:
     { id: 7996082,
       id_str: '7996082',
       name: 'EL PAÍS',
       screen_name: 'el_pais',
       location: 'Madrid',
       description:
        'Las noticias más relevantes y la última hora, por los periodistas de EL PAÍS. Para informarse y conversar. Únete al sistema de alertas mediante mensaje directo',
       url: 'https://t.co/0o6oj1LRF2',
       entities: [Object],
       protected: false,
       followers_count: 6878154,
       friends_count: 755,
       listed_count: 56357,
       created_at: 'Mon Aug 06 16:20:09 +0000 2007',
       favourites_count: 1657,
       utc_offset: null,
       time_zone: null,
       geo_enabled: true,
       verified: true,
       statuses_count: 473495,
       lang: 'es',
       contributors_enabled: false,
       is_translator: false,
       is_translation_enabled: true,
       profile_background_color: 'FFFFFF',
       profile_background_image_url: 'http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png',
       profile_background_image_url_https: 'https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png',
       profile_background_tile: false,
       profile_image_url:
        'http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/815456059322036224/o_RQNEOh_normal.jpg',
       profile_image_url_https:
        'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/815456059322036224/o_RQNEOh_normal.jpg',
       profile_banner_url: 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/7996082/1450772084',
       profile_link_color: '0084B4',
       profile_sidebar_border_color: 'FFFFFF',
       profile_sidebar_fill_color: 'F1F4F9',
       profile_text_color: '333333',
       profile_use_background_image: false,
       has_extended_profile: true,
       default_profile: false,
       default_profile_image: false,
       following: true,
       follow_request_sent: false,
       notifications: false,
       translator_type: 'none' },
    geo: null,
    coordinates: null,
    place: null,
    contributors: null,
    is_quote_status: false,
    retweet_count: 1,
    favorite_count: 7,
    favorited: false,
    retweeted: false,
    possibly_sensitive: false,
    lang: 'es' },
    { created_at: 'Mon Apr 08 07:55:29 +0000 2019',
    id: 1115161225120366600,
    id_str: '1115161225120366593',
    text:
     'RT @demamasdepapas: Opinión | Niños que pegan: por qué agreden y cómo enseñarles a no hacerlo; por Ruth Alfonso Arias\nhttps://t.co/XiJoSqUi…',
    truncated: false,
    entities:
     { hashtags: [], symbols: [], user_mentions: [Array], urls: [] },
    source:
     '<a href="https://about.twitter.com/products/tweetdeck" rel="nofollow">TweetDeck</a>',
    in_reply_to_status_id: null,
    in_reply_to_status_id_str: null,
    in_reply_to_user_id: null,
    in_reply_to_user_id_str: null,
    in_reply_to_screen_name: null,
    user:
     { id: 7996082,
       id_str: '7996082',
       name: 'EL PAÍS',
       screen_name: 'el_pais',
       location: 'Madrid',
       description:
        'Las noticias más relevantes y la última hora, por los periodistas de EL PAÍS. Para informarse y conversar. Únete al sistema de alertas mediante mensaje directo',
       url: 'https://t.co/0o6oj1LRF2',
       entities: [Object],
       protected: false,
       followers_count: 6878154,
       friends_count: 755,
       listed_count: 56357,
       created_at: 'Mon Aug 06 16:20:09 +0000 2007',
       favourites_count: 1657,
       utc_offset: null,
       time_zone: null,
       geo_enabled: true,
       verified: true,
       statuses_count: 473495,
       lang: 'es',
       contributors_enabled: false,
       is_translator: false,
       is_translation_enabled: true,
       profile_background_color: 'FFFFFF',
       profile_background_image_url: 'http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png',
       profile_background_image_url_https: 'https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png',
       profile_background_tile: false,
       profile_image_url:
        'http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/815456059322036224/o_RQNEOh_normal.jpg',
       profile_image_url_https:
        'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/815456059322036224/o_RQNEOh_normal.jpg',
       profile_banner_url: 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/7996082/1450772084',
       profile_link_color: '0084B4',
       profile_sidebar_border_color: 'FFFFFF',
       profile_sidebar_fill_color: 'F1F4F9',
       profile_text_color: '333333',
       profile_use_background_image: false,
       has_extended_profile: true,
       default_profile: false,
       default_profile_image: false,
       following: true,
       follow_request_sent: false,
       notifications: false,
       translator_type: 'none' },
    geo: null,
    coordinates: null,
    place: null,
    contributors: null,
    retweeted_status:
     { created_at: 'Mon Apr 08 07:55:16 +0000 2019',
       id: 1115161170388844500,
       id_str: '1115161170388844544',
       text:
        'Opinión | Niños que pegan: por qué agreden y cómo enseñarles a no hacerlo; por Ruth Alfonso Arias\nhttps://t.co/XiJoSqUiJL',
       truncated: false,
       entities: [Object],
       source:
        '<a href="https://about.twitter.com/products/tweetdeck" rel="nofollow">TweetDeck</a>',
       in_reply_to_status_id: null,
       in_reply_to_status_id_str: null,
       in_reply_to_user_id: null,
       in_reply_to_user_id_str: null,
       in_reply_to_screen_name: null,
       user: [Object],
       geo: null,
       coordinates: null,
       place: null,
       contributors: null,
       is_quote_status: false,
       retweet_count: 6,
       favorite_count: 12,
       favorited: false,
       retweeted: false,
       possibly_sensitive: false,
       lang: 'es' },
    is_quote_status: false,
    retweet_count: 6,
    favorite_count: 0,
    favorited: false,
    retweeted: false,
    lang: 'es' }
  ];
  
  // Recorremos los elementos del array:
  
  tweets.forEach((tweet) => {
    console.log('User id: ', tweet.user.id);
    console.log('User name: ', tweet.user.name);
    console.log('User location: ', tweet.user.location);
  });
```

Como puedes ver, he utilizado el método [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach), el cual permite recorrer cada elemento de un `Array`.

```
tweets.forEach((tweet) => {
    console.log('User Id: ', tweet.user.id);
    console.log('User Name: ', tweet.user.name);
    console.log('User Location: ', tweet.user.location);
});
```

Para cada elemento del `Array` se ejecuta la función que se pasa como parámetro a `forEach()`. En este caso, la variable `tweet` representa un elemento del `Array`. Según lo que vimos de la estructura de nuestro *Response*, cada elemento tiene un valor `user`, y es por esto que para obtener el valor deseado usamos `tweet.user.valor`.

Espero que esto aclare tu duda.